# Eclipse import deleted all XML files

Tags: android

I imported my project about 30 minutes ago using Android->Existing Code->MyProject.
Eclipse completely deleted every xml file. This is a huge project. I don't know what to do!!!

Comment: Is your project not in version control?

Comment: Restore from a backup or from version control.

Comment: I don't think so. My .project files and others were also deleted. I have APK

Comment: I don't have a backup. Version control? :( Sorry. I only recently published 2 apps in Google Play. I'm not familiar with version control.

Comment: The app has like 1000 users. I can't change projects

Comment: Do I have to retype 10 hours of xml?

Comment: Learning can be painful at times...

Comment: Any advice? Kind sir....

Comment: should i reverse engineer my own apk lol

Comment: The question doesn't really have anything specific to work with. All we can do is to remind you to cover your behind with version control and backups.

Comment: What do you want me to ask?

Comment: How much more specific can I be?

Comment: I removed a project from the workspace a few days ago. Today I tried to import it with: File-Import-Android-Existing Code. When it appeared in the workspace all xml files were (are) 0kb

Comment: Don't use "Existing code" if you have an already functioning android project. Just do File->Import->General->Existing projects into workspace

Comment: I didn't plan for my development environment to erase all my work. Nope. Didn't do that.

Comment: So the xml files are actually deleted from your hard drive too and not just failing to import?

Comment: No. They are there. Just empty.

Comment: Do java decomilers give you xml?

Comment: There is no 'replace' option when I right click.

Comment: Try checking out this link. According to this its under Team->Show local history http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-55.htm

Comment: Also this: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-87b.htm

Comment: I'm sorry. The "Replace wish" option is there. It's just not usable

Comment: I'm trying to figure out apktool...

Comment: OH WOW!!!! APKTOOL GIVES YOU EXACT CODE.

Comment: yay! party time. now back that code up.. back it up so hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [APKTool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) it may get your XML back for you. After that, either make backups of your code regularly or look into setting up a version control system for yourself.

Comment: Yes. I will now surely. This mystical version control that you all speak of sounds handy.

Comment: Recovered my exact code. Brilliant. Copying to usb drive now!

Comment: Not exact code. Manifest was missing a couple things. Typeface was corrupted. Minor tweeeks is all. :)

Comment: Nothing is easy in this life. Lesson learned. Version control. Sorry for wasting anyone's time.